# A werewolf short story first read in the mid 80s, about a cheating man

Tags: story-identification, werewolf, love

I believe this short story was in an anthology I read at my school library in the mid 1980s (similar to Alfred Hitchock's Monster Museum); the story involved a man who was engaged to a rich society lady, and yet fell in love with a woman who turned out to be a werewolf. In the end, she kills his fiancee and family so that they can be together, to his horror.